# margin or padding above text in css

Tags: css

I'm working on this page:

[image]

I'm trying to get the first dropline items to display a little further down from the main menu; say approximately half the distance as there is between the first and second droplines.  The reason being that when mousing over the first dropline, it's very easy to have the mouse go back to the main menu.

```
/* ================================================================ 
This copyright notice must be untouched at all times.

The original version of this stylesheet and the associated (x)html
is available at http://www.cssplay.co.uk/pro_dropline7.html
Copyright (c) 2005-2008 Stu Nicholls. All rights reserved.
This stylesheet and the associated (x)html may be modified in any 
way to fit your requirements.
=================================================================== */

#dropline {position:relative; font-size:13px; height:40px; background:url(http://test.garlandcountydemocrats.org/MASTER_files/back.gif);}

#dropline, #dropline ul {padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; width:1080px;}

#dropline table {border-collapse:collapse; margin:-1px -10px; 0 0; padding:0; width:0; height:0; font-size:13px;}
#dropline li {float:left; height:40px; margin-right:1px;}
#dropline li a {float:left; display:block; height:40px; line-height:19px; padding:0 20px 0 10px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;}
#dropline li a.down {background:background:url(http://test.garlandcountydemocrats.org/MASTER_files/down.gif) no-repeat right center;}
#dropline li ul li a.down {font-size:15px; color:#ff0; font-weight:normal;}

#dropline li a:hover {white-space:nowrap; color:#444;}
#dropline li a.down:hover {white-space:nowrap; color:#444; background:background:url(http://test.garlandcountydemocrats.org/MASTER_files/down-over.gif) no-repeat right center;}

#dropline li:hover > a {color:#4AEF03;}
#dropline li:hover > a.down {color:#4AEF03; background:url(http://test.garlandcountydemocrats.org/MASTER_files/down-over.gif) no-repeat right center;}

#dropline li ul {position:absolute; top:38px; left:-9999px; z-index:10; background:url(http://test.garlandcountydemocrats.org/MASTER_files/sub-back.png) left top;}
#dropline li ul.floatRight li {float:right;}

#dropline :hover ul,
#dropline :hover ul :hover ul,
#dropline :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul,
#dropline :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul,
#dropline :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul {left:0; background:url(http://test.garlandcountydemocrats.org/MASTER_files/sub-back.png) left bottom;}

#dropline :hover ul ul,
#dropline :hover ul :hover ul ul,
#dropline :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul ul,
#dropline :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul ul {left:-9999px; top:38px; background:transparent;}

I've tried several different variations on the css code shown below without success.  I'm a total newbie so any help will certainly be appreciated.  Thanks in advance. Hozey
```

Comment: Try to make jsfiddle demonstration of your code.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what the problem is. Please include a screenshot of intended result, or at least describe what you want to do on the image.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `padding-top` to `#dropline li ul`

CSS:

```
#dropline li ul {position:absolute; padding-top:14px; top:38px; left:-9999px; z-index:10; background:url(http://test.garlandcountydemocrats.org/MASTER_files/sub-back.png) left top;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CGctj/1/